# What is fastest way to read file in python loop and avoid collisions with other program writing occasionally into the same file?

Tags: python, linux, real-time

I have a python program A reading file F 10 times in a second. Another program B provides update values to file F once in 30 minutes.
What programming method is best, if reading loop should be running as fast and CPU cyclewise as lightweight as possible, but writing is not time critical.
Interruption of the python code for a second in 30 minutes is acceptable if normal looping is fast possible.

Should I use locks, interrupts, threads or queues to keep read loop as lightweight and fast as possible?

Comment: You'll have to figure out a way for the two programs to cooperate. Using a lock file might be a feasible approach. There's non-standard module available on PyPi called *fasteners* which you may find helpful

Comment: You can create a third program which provides some kind of API for readers/writers.

Comment: Why are you reading data that is not changing multiple times?  Read the data once and don't read it again until it changes.  You have tagged linux; inotify has been available since ~2005, so unless you are using a really old kernel you should probably just wait for a notification from inotify before you read the data again.